# Modify JS files using another JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How can I edit a JS file (containing a JSON object) using another JS file?

Example:
JS file to be edited (eslintrc.js):

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,

  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },

  env: {
    browser: true
  }
}
```

And I want to let's say add additional configuration lets say in:

```
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  }
```

I tried doing something like:

```
fs = require('fs');
var m = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('.eslintrc.js'));
console.log(m)
```

But of course, as expected, I am getting errors.

```
undefined:1
module.exports = {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

To also add, this is not the only file I need to update. There are several others that look similar in nature but not exactly the same such as:

```
module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
    // --> boot files are part of "main.js"
    boot: [
    ],

    css: [
      'custom.scss'
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I open the JS file and be able to edit the JSON object inside without distoring the actual JS file?

Thank you!

Comment: `eslintrc.js` is a JavaScript file. If you want to edit it, you will have to parse into an AST, make the changes, then re-print the file. If you want to use JSON, you will need to convert the file.

Answer (score 0):

You must eliminate `'module.exports ='` from `eslintrc.js` in order to parse it with `JSON.parse` function.

Comment: Yes, I do know that. And how do you suggest I do that? Thanks